# Is it possible to change a number of filenames to be the file extension in bash?

Tags: bash, filenames

I have a number files which all have the same basename ($FILENAME), each with its own unique extension. I am trying to set the extension as the filename (no extensions).

I have tried a few different approaches, with my most recent being:

```
find . -type f -name "$FILENAME" -exec sh -c 'x="{}"; mv "$FILENAME.$x" "${x}"' \;
```

Comment: Are all these files in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, they're all in the same directory.

Comment: Perhaps `for f in "$FILENAME"*; do mv "$f" "${f##*.}"; done` would do the trick?

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you! @jared_mamrot

Comment: No problem - I'll make it an answer

Comment: @jared_mamrot could you link me to some resources on ## in bash? I am now trying to do the opposite (i.e. make the filename the extension with the filename becoming $FILENAME).

Comment: It's all documented in the bash manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html / here is a good introduction with examples: https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#from_the_beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a for loop to cycle through the files beginning with "$FILENAME", e.g.

```
for f in "$FILENAME"*
do
    mv "$f" "${f##*.}"
done
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
for f in "$FILENAME"*; do mv "$f" "${f##*.}"; done
```